# No se muestra la pantalla de Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, iis

He estado intentando mostrar la pantalla de Login como se deberia de mostrar, pero lo que hace es mostrarme como un directorio de las carpetas que posee el proyecto, he estado batallando con el web.config, pero no da resultado, he hecho algunos cambios iis pero tampoco funciona, hay alguna forma que pueda hacer para mostrar el login? adjunto una imagen como se ve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi como esta imagen se deberia de ver en el iis:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

deberia de ser un login funcional, pero no es asi, si intento acceder alguno de esos directorios que se ven en la primera imagen, retorna error, no se si hay que configurar algo como:

> **default page**

la duda si es asi, es como configurarlo

tengo algunas configuraciones que he ido agregando porque me ha dado otros problemas mas, asi como estas

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
         <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    

    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Gracias por tomarse su tiempo, hay alguna ayuda que podria brindarme, muchas gracias

Comment: y como estan configurados tus controladores?

Comment: tenes algun controlador que se llame Base? deberias entrar por http://localhost/index -> homecontroller

Comment: no, solo HomeController, pero igual no me redirecciona hacia la vista y como comente, si doy click alguna carpeta, me devuelve el error
**Handler "BlockViewHandler" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list**